# Why is the same Magic method I used in the following code generating different output than what is expected

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hour=0, minute=0, second=0):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(self.hour, self.minute, self.second)

    def __add__(self, other_time):

        new_time = Time()
        if (self.second + other_time.second) >= 60:
            self.minute += 1
            new_time.second = (self.second + other_time.second) - 60
        else:
            new_time.second = self.second + other_time.second

        if (self.minute + other_time.minute) >= 60:
            self.hour += 1
            new_time.minute = (self.minute + other_time.minute) - 60
        else:
            new_time.minute = self.minute + other_time.minute

        if (self.hour + other_time.hour) > 24:
            new_time.hour = (self.hour + other_time.hour) - 24
        else:
            new_time.hour = self.hour + other_time.hour

        return new_time

    def __sub__(self, other_time):

        new_time = Time()
        if (self.second + other_time.second) >= 60:
            self.minute += 1
            new_time.second = (self.second + other_time.second) - 60
        else:
            new_time.second = self.second + other_time.second

        if (self.minute + other_time.minute) >= 60:
            self.hour += 1
            new_time.minute = (self.minute + other_time.minute) - 60
        else:
            new_time.minute = self.minute + other_time.minute

        if (self.hour + other_time.hour) > 24:
            new_time.hour = (self.hour + other_time.hour) - 24
        else:
            new_time.hour = self.hour + other_time.hour

        return new_time


def main():
    time1 = Time(1, 20, 10)

    print(time1)

    time2 = Time(24, 41, 30)

    print(time1 + time2)
    print(time1 - time2)


main()
```

In the class Time, I have defined methods **add** and **sub** with the same function(basically they are the same methods with a different call).
when I run print(time1 + time2), print(time1 -time2) I expect to get the same output. But Instead, I end up getting the following output.

```
Output: 
1:20:10
2:01:40
3:01:40
expected Output:
1:20:10
2:01:40
2:01:40
```

I would be glad if someone can point out a way to interpret the above code with respect to the output it generates, or explain what is actually happening when I run the above code that is leading to the output generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines `self.minute += 1` and `self.hour += 1` mean that your `__add__` and `__sub__` both modify the left-hand argument to `+`/`-`.  Thus, after evaluating `time1 + time2`, the value of `time1` will be different, so you'll get a different answer when you then evaluate `time1 - time2`.

Answer (score 0):

I have trying out your code and found out the following: after the instruction

```
Time(time1+time2)
```

is run, the value of time1 is now 2:20:10, so when the second method is done the hours will be (24+2)-24 instead of (24+1)-24